# How to print the frequency of words in perl?

Tags: perl

```
open INP,"<C:\\Users\\hanadi\\Documents\\cs.txt";
while ($line=<INP>)
{
    chomp($line);
    @list=split/\s+/,$line;
    foreach $w (@list)
    {
        $wordfreq{$w}++;
    }
}
foreach $w2(keys>wordfreq)
{
    print "$w2==>$wordfreq{$w}";
}
```

I want to print each word and its frequency.now i want code in Perl to jump  and Print the above information for the next

ranks (>100), but do not print

every line, print only one line for every 1000 words (otherwise there will

be too many lines to print) in decreasing order of frequency and

decreasing alphabetical order among words with the same frequency.

Comment: `cs.txt`? This reeks of homework...

Comment: you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: (1) `use strict; use warnings` (2) `keys>wordfreq` should be a syntax error – you probably wanted `keys %wordfreq` (3) You aren't outputting a frequency, but an absolute count: `freq = count/total_word_count`

Comment: yes this is a homework the doctor told us to write a programm in perl to print frequency of words in text and then print the top 100

Answer (score 2):

The first issue of this problem is to define the word "word."  Am assuming, by one of your comments, that punctuation is not part of a "word," since you were asking how to *"...delete punctuations from the text..."*

One solution to this is to use a regex to capture only "word" characters, i.e., alphanumeric and underscore, by matching the text against `\w` in the regex.

Building a hash, where the keys are the words and the associated values are the counts, is the way to go.  However, when doing this, you need to insure that the keys are all the same case, i.e., either all UPPER or all lower.

After you've built this hash, you can sort the output in descending order by the has values (frequency) and use a counter to print just the top 100 words.  There will be words with the same frequency count--especially having only one occurrence.  How do you want these printed, as it can make a difference whether they appear in the list of top 100.  I'd suggest ordering these cases alphabetically.

Give the above, consider the following solution, which uses the text above the code below as the corpus:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

open my $fh, '<', 'words.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    $hash{ lc $1 }++ while /(\w+)/g;
}
close $fh;

my $i = 1;

for my $word ( sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} || $a cmp $b } keys %hash ) {
    print "$i. $word: ($hash{$word})\n" if $i++ < 100 or !( $i % 1000 );
}
```

Partial output:

```
1. the: (22)
2. to: (8)
3. a: (5)
4. you: (5)
5. is: (4)
6. of: (4)
7. this: (4)
8. word: (4)
9. all: (3)
10. and: (3)
...
96. punctuation: (1)
97. punctuations: (1)
98. since: (1)
99. sort: (1)
100. suggest: (1)
```

Limitations:

One issue that results from capturing word characters can be seen in cases of some possessive forms of words, e.g., `word's`.  In this case, both `word` and `s` would be captured as words.  If you want to retain such punctuation, and `split` on whitespace, you can just use the following instead of the regex line:

```
$hash{ lc $_ }++ for split ' ';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank u very much.. but i need help now i want code in Perl to jump  and Print the above information for the next 

ranks (>100), but do not print

every line, print only one line for every 1000 words (otherwise there will

be too many lines to print) in decreasing order of frequency and

decreasing alphabetical order among words with the same frequency.

Comment: //stackoverflow.com/users/1364945/kenosis

Comment: @user3370510 - Have modified the code to print every thousandth word after printing the first 100.  Notice that it uses the modulo operator in the expression `!( $i % 1000 )`.  When the value of `$i` is 1000, the remainder will be 0, so !0 will be evaluated to true and the line will print.

Answer (score 0):

please pay attention to all of amons reply, and always rtq. (good spot amon).

(i have determined) your problem is that once you have constructed your wordcount hash, you now need to invert the hash so you can sort the values into some kind of order. The problem with this is that more than one word may have the same count and would overwrite earlier stored words.

To do this you need to store an array in a hash value, and this is done by using a reference to an array. Hash values may only be scalars, an array is not a scalar, but a reference to an array is.

In this re-write of your problem, I have updated the open and close calls to use scalar filehandles, with appropriate error handling (or die), and converted your foreach statements into 'maps'. These can take a bit of time to grasp so do not copy and paste them. Rather, focus on the inverting of the hash and how the array is accessed. This is possibly quite complex for you so I have left this parts in foreach style.

The 'each' keyword takes a key/value pair from the hash, and is often used this way to process hashes in while statements.

You will still need to work on converting the counts into frequencies as per amons suggestion and retrieving the top 100. There is a clue to the counting in the '$c' variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# word count #wct.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (%wordfreq);

open my $input, '<', 'wc.txt'
 or die "cannot open wc txt file $!";

map { $wordfreq{ $_ }++; } (split /\s+/, $_) while <$input> ;

close $input
  or die "cannot close wc txt file $!";

# print (
# map {"$_ has ". $wordfreq{$_} . "\n" } (keys %wordfreq)
# );

foreach (keys %wordfreq){
#  print "$_ has ". $wordfreq{$_} . "\n"
}


my %invertedhash;

while (my ($key,$value) = each %wordfreq){

   push @{$invertedhash{$value}}, $key;

}

my $c;

foreach (reverse sort keys %invertedhash){

last if $c++ == 2;
print "words with a count of $_ are @{$invertedhash{$_}} \n";

}

exit 0;
```

sample

```
one two two
three three three four
four four four five
five five five
```

produces

```
words with a count of 4 are four five
words with a count of 3 are three
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now if iwant to delete punctuations from the text can i use tr function or what?